# Error on offline node deploy

Tags: singlestore

When I try to initialize the cluster in offline mode (VM host doesn't have internet access) with webUI or with the following command

```
memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role single_box
```

I get this error:

> J369767 [ERROR] Failed to download MemSQL: File with type MEMSQL and version d78c76bb960feb6e38a46977e7c95c2de7838c1e was added with file hash 911230f9e35a42cb756b0cc27398b9c1 but now has file hash None

However, the `memsqlbin_amd64` file was previously successfully added with this command:

```
memsql-ops file-add -t memsql /memsql/distr/memsqlbin_amd64.tar.gz
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, this was my installation mistake. Now solved

Comment: Can you answer with how you solved it?  I am curious how you got Ops into that state.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the singlestore Tools on the server.
I would rather suggest to follow the guidelines mentioned in the official documentation [link](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/user-and-cluster-administration/cluster-management-with-tools/singlestore-tools-installation.html).